# Python set class for static method argument

Tags: python, class, static-methods

When trying to specify class for static method arguments, as for example:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def staticm(param1: A):
        return 1
```

It raises an error that `'A' is not defined`.

Why I can't do this? and is there a loophole?

I can just check with `isinstance`... But why this is not allowed in python?

Comment: The problem is at the point of the definition `A` is not yet fully defined (because it's currently being defined).  For python 3.5, the only answer was to use 'A' as a string.  But I don't know I thought they heard they made things better in later versions.

Comment: It's still the case as @saquites says. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id28

Comment: Also for the record, `isinstance` is not the same thing as a typing hint. Nothing is actually enforcing the typing hints.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comment of @saquintes.

Solution: add class `A` as a String `'A'`

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def staticm(param1: 'A'):
        return 1
```